# Create non-existent functions by a single click in VS Code Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tdd

Other IDE's like PyCharm, IntelliJ, etc. have a feature where if it finds a function being called that is undefined, you can right-click it and click 'create method' or something similar to automatically create the function definition. It helps out a lot in TDD. Is there something similar in VS Code?

Comment: with [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) you can configure your own custom code actions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) extension, here is a simple example:

Configure in `settings.json` file:

```json
// settings.json file
{
    "my-code-actions.actions": {
        "[python]": {
        "create new methond {{diag:$1}}": {
            "diagnostics": ["\"(.*?)\" is not defined"],
            "text": "def {{diag:$1}}():\n    pass\n",
            "where": "afterLast",
        }
        }
    }
}
```

*The effect when writing code after saving this setting:*

[image]

[image]

[image]

***Another method that might be useful:***

open in sequence **File** > **Preferences** > **Configure User Snippets**. Select **python** in the command palette. This will create a `python.json` file in which you can customize the code segment according to the rules.

*A simple example:*

```json
    "Print to console":{
        "prefix": "defHello",
        "body": [
            "def Hello():",
            "${1:    }print('Hello worle')",
            "$2",
        ],
        "description": "print hello world"
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using My Code Actions is not working for me. If I use an undeclared function, I get the info "no code actions available". Is your solution still up to date?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there's nothing like this built in to the Microsoft Python extensions, but a request for it is in the backlog for Pylance: [Add support for create function, class or parameter code actions depending on context #5368](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/5368). You'd then be able to use the quick fix menu (<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>). I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".